# Android ActionBar onOptionsItemSelected() (click) on a wrong position,

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity which include ViewPager with 5 fragments, they also can change with tabs, At first my onOptionsItemSelected() work as needed, its call showPopupMenu();  and click come on whole view menu item, but when I switch to other fragment, and go back, click come to menu item bottom position, and to do clcik is very hard,

my menu item

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/label_all_posts_fragment_base"
        android:title="@string/label_all_posts"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"

        />
```

my menu create methods

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.pop_up_menu, menu);
    mMenu = menu;

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.label_all_posts_fragment_base);
    if (item != null) {
        switch (mPostMode){
            case POSTS_ALL:
                item.setTitle(R.string.label_all_posts);
                break;
            case POSTS_MY:
                item.setTitle(R.string.label_my_posts);
                break;
            case POSTS_FAVORITE:
                item.setTitle(R.string.label_favorites);
                break;
        }
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and item click method

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.label_all_posts_fragment_base:
            showPopupMenu();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

normal time

[image]

after navigation to other fragments
[image]

i can't understand why item click position is changed,

Comment: thank you for trying to understand,    at the normal time, when we click on the ActionBar.s item, that click place depends ActionBar height (as match_parent), but in this case, after navigation to other fragment, it clicks on the bottom of action bar view, (I will put the picture),   My fragments in the view pager, and they managing from MainActivity, (i'll put code above), and I use AppCompat DarkActionbar, which init in the baseActivity. i am sorry but my rating does not late to add image

Comment: I can't click on ActionBar menu item Title (the text don't handle click) ,

Comment: and there are a Verbose,  W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Hi! that problem have solved, it will be sounds not seriously, but it solved itself..